# Enabling forward secrecy / ECDHE_RSA on Apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2

I'm trying to enable ECDHE_RSA on my server. I'm running Apache2 and OpenSSL. In my `ssl.conf` file, I have tried to make this work with these configs:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv3 -SSLv2
SSLCompression Off
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

When I check the certificate in my browser, it's still using `DHE_RSA` when I expect it to be using `ECDHE_RSA`.

I've also tried adding these config lines in my `sites-enabled/default-ssl`. Without success, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something was wrong with my OpenSSL installation. Simply running an upgrade command on my server fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```